# SSRS - Align zero on primary and secondary axis

Tags: reporting-services, bar-chart

I'm working on an SSRS Chart and I have two Y-axis. The primary is a number which includes negative value. The secondary is a percentage with only positive values. Now, my problem is the zeros on both axis don't align. Is there anyway I can make it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be difficult to do perfectly.

You can get close by setting the min value on your **Secondary** Axis to be some negative number. You would have to determine the number by looking at you primary axis values.

[image]

In the example you show, your primary axis starts at -100 which is 20% of the positive end of the axis (500). So in this case, if you set the min value of your secondary axis to -0.2 (-20%) then the zeros should be aligned.

Of course, to work this out based on your data will take a little more maths but it should point you in the right direction.

The formula would look something like this...

```
= 
(FLOOR(Min(Fields!AmountA.Value)/100)*100)
/
(CEILING(Max(Fields!AmountA.Value)/100)*100)
```

AmountA is the data on your primary axis

So, **Min** AmountA = `-51`, divide by 100 = `-0.51`, apply floor = `-1`, multiply by 100 = `-100`

**Max** AmountA = `457`, divide by 100 = `4.57`, apply ceiling = `5`,  x 100 = `500`

So, -100/500 = `-0.2` (which will be -20% on your secondary axis).